# ASP.net List with custom object

Tags: asp.net, list

I have a class Student:

```
Student
{
    string studentName{get;set;}
    string studentEmail {get;set;}
    int studentGrade {get;set;}
    int studentId {get;set;}
}
```

and I have a list

```
List<student> students = new List<student>();
```

How can I find a student by `studentName`?

Would this work?

```
student.Contains(somestudentName);
```

Or do I have to override some functions?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might look into the [Linq library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/). It's built into .NET and has method for working with collections of objects. But first...have you tried the straightforward approach of iterating through the list with a loop, and checking the name property of each student to find the one you want? Before you get any nice abstractions, it'd be good if you understood the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to find **the only one student**, you can use `LINQ`:

```
Student student = students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.studentName.Equals(someStudentName));
```

Take a note that it might return a `NULL` value.